# oracle ora-32040, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I can't compile this procedure, I have a ORA-32040
Description: recursive WITH clause must use a UNION ALL operation. Below procedure I paste a code with example data set and object definitions.

Please let me know how to rewrite that procedure. I used union all operation but it doesn't work.

```sql
create or replace procedure ra_hi_proc is 
begin
insert into ra_hi_tab (
select *
from(
  with
  rh (edate, st, c_ra) as (
    select *
    from ra_hi
    where trunc(cast(edate as date)) = to_date(sysdate)
  ),
  r1 (edate, st, c_ra) as (
    select *
    from ra_hi
    where trunc(cast(edate as date)) = to_date(sysdate-1)
  ),
  sto(st_number) as (
    select st_number
    from stor
    )

  select *
  from (
    select a.*, b.st
    from rh a
      left join r1 b
        on a.st = b.st
  )
  
  union all
  
  select rh.date, st_number, 0, null
  from rh, sto
  where st_number not in (
    select st
    from rh
  )
));

commit;
end;
```

```sql
create table ra_hi (edate date , st VARCHAR2(20), c_ra number);
```

```sql
Insert into ra_hi (EDATE,ST,C_RA) values (to_date('22-11-2020','dd-mm-yyyy'),'1875','2');
Insert into ra_hi (EDATE,ST,C_RA) values (to_date('09-12-2020','dd-mm-yyyy'),'1285','1');
Insert into ra_hi (EDATE,ST,C_RA) values (to_date('28-12-2020','dd-mm-yyyy'),'1146','2');
Insert into ra_hi (EDATE,ST,C_RA) values (to_date('13-01-2021','dd-mm-yyyy'),'1589','2');
Insert into ra_hi (EDATE,ST,C_RA) values (to_date('12-01-2021','dd-mm-yyyy'),'1021','2');
Insert into ra_hi (EDATE,ST,C_RA) values (to_date('07-01-2021','dd-mm-yyyy'),'1138','2');
Insert into ra_hi (EDATE,ST,C_RA) values (to_date('28-12-2020','dd-mm-yyyy'),'1233','2');
Insert into ra_hi (EDATE,ST,C_RA) values (to_date('19-12-2020','dd-mm-yyyy'),'1492','2');
Insert into ra_hi (EDATE,ST,C_RA) values (to_date('08-12-2020','dd-mm-yyyy'),'1138','2');
Insert into ra_hi (EDATE,ST,C_RA) values (to_date('24-11-2020','dd-mm-yyyy'),'1499','2');
```

```sql
create table stor (st_number varchar2(20));
```

```sql
Insert into STOR (ST_NUMBER) values ('1674');
Insert into STOR (ST_NUMBER) values ('1078');
Insert into STOR (ST_NUMBER) values ('1079');
Insert into STOR (ST_NUMBER) values ('1081');
Insert into STOR (ST_NUMBER) values ('1082');
Insert into STOR (ST_NUMBER) values ('1084');
Insert into STOR (ST_NUMBER) values ('1092');
Insert into STOR (ST_NUMBER) values ('1093');
Insert into STOR (ST_NUMBER) values ('1094');
Insert into STOR (ST_NUMBER) values ('1095');
```

```sql
create table ra_hi_tab (
edate   DATE
ST  VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
C_RA    NUMBER
ST_S    VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
```

Comment: Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), because we cannot run or rewrite your query without data definitions, but manual parsing is very inefficient (and can be done by yourself to locate the problematic piece). BTW this is the query I wish I had never supported, because of mixture of `with` in the `from`,  join trough `where` condition and `select from select from select...`. If you rewrite it to use only `with` or only highly indented nested `select`s you'll easily find the reason.

Comment: @astentx I've edited my question.  I had to use `select from select from...` . Without it I had a `ORA-32034`

Comment: `SYSDATE` returns a `DATE` value, never use `TO_DATE(...)` on a value which is already a `DATE`. `cast(edate as date)` is basically the same and also useless. Also `DATE` is a reserved keyword, you should not use it as column or variable name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This compiles without errors:

```sql
create or replace procedure ra_hi_proc is 
begin
  insert into ra_hi_tab (edate, st, c_ra, st_s)
    with rh (edate, st, c_ra) as (
      select edate, st, c_ra
      from ra_hi
      where trunc(edate) = trunc(sysdate)
    ),
    r1 (edate, st, c_ra) as (
      select *
      from ra_hi
      where trunc(edate) = trunc(sysdate-1)
    ),
    sto(st_number) as (
      select st_number
      from stor
    )
    select a.edate, a.st, a.c_ra, b.st
    from   rh a
           left join r1 b
           on a.st = b.st
    union all
    select rh.edate, st_number, 0, null
    from   rh
           CROSS JOIN sto
    where st_number not in (select st from rh);
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=85dce846a0e78591a1dcdde0dfc6c44d)*

Note:

- You question does not tell us what you intend the output to be so I cannot verify the output of the procedure.
- You are filtering on today and yesterday and your sample data has neither of those dates so it does not appear to do anything.
- Do not use `TO_DATE` on a value that is already a `DATE` (such as `SYSDATE`).
- Do not mix the ANSI join syntax and the legacy comma-join syntax.
- Do not use `COMMIT` in a procedure (or function); use it in the block that calls the procedure (or function) as this allows you to chain multiple procedures together and `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` them as a single transaction. If you `COMMIT` in each procedure then you are unable to `ROLLBACK`.
- I am not sure you intended to use a `CROSS JOIN`; however, you did use one so I have just replicated it (see note 1).

Answer (score 0):

Your query has several issue, see my comment. I don't see any reason for recursive CTE. Without having a look at the details, the statement could be much simpler like this:

```
insert into ra_hi (
WITH rh AS (
    SELECT edate, st, c_ra
    FROM v_ra_hi
    WHERE trunc(edate) = trunc(sysdate)
  )
SELECT a.*, b.st
FROM v_ra_hi a
   LEFT JOIN rh b ON a.st = b.st
WHERE a.trunc(edate) = trunc(sysdate-1)
UNION ALL  
SELECT rh.edate, st_number, 0, NULL
FROM rh 
    CROSS JOIN stor@scd
WHERE re = 1
    and st_number NOT IN (SELECT st FROM rh);
```

Comment: it doesn't work. I've received ORA-32034, when I add `select * from...` to your code I have the same ORA error as before

Comment: There is no recursive CTE in the OP's code; they use `UNION ALL` in a `SELECT` statement that is outside sub-queries defined by the `WITH` clause so there is no recursion.

Comment: In deed, I mixed "recursive" with "CTE with parenthesized list"